# Why UITextView height become dynamic only on scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UITableCell` i wanted to make it height dynamic according to it's size. So i have used the following code.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

This code works just fine but the issue is my UITextView height becomes dynamic only when i scroll otherwise on load of `UITableView` it does not become dynamic height.Although method is called twice.Please tell me why this happend?

**EDIT:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell for row called %d",(int)[arr_post count]);
    //define variables here
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeStr;
    NSAttributedString *attributeStr;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homeCell";
    HomeCell *cell = [self.table_view
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                         forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


    //get the post data
    Post *user_post=[arr_post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   //set the button tags
    cell.btn_like.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.btn_comment.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.btn_fav.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.btn_con.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.btn_book.tag=indexPath.row;

    //add info to buttons
    cell.btn_like.selected=user_post.isPostLiked;
    cell.btn_comment.selected=user_post.isPostCommented;
    cell.btn_fav.selected=user_post.isPostFavourite;
    cell.btn_con.selected=user_post.isPostCondolence;
    cell.btn_book.selected=user_post.isPostBookmarked;
    //add text view path

    //add user info
    cell.label_name.text=user_post.username;
    [cell.img_profile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.user_profileImage]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

    //add location
    if([user_post.location isEqualToString:@"Not Available"])
    {
        [cell.img_icon_location setHidden:true];
        [cell.label_location setHidden:true];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.label_location.text=user_post.location;

    }
    //ad post info
    cell.tv_post.text=user_post.post_description;
    cell.tv_post.font = [UIFont fontWithName:user_post.font_family size:[user_post.font_size floatValue]];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:user_post.modification_date];
    if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {

    }
    else
    {
        UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
        cell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
        UIImageView *tv_image =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
        [tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];
        [cell.tv_post addSubview:tv_image];

    }
    //make textview height dynamic
    cell.tv_post.scrollEnabled=NO;
    [self textViewDidChange:cell.tv_post];


    NSLog(@"textview height is %f",cell.tv_post.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"main view height is %f",cell.view_tvContainer.frame.size.height);
    //set the border of uiview
    cell.view_tvContainer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.view_tvContainer.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;


    //set the like count
    NSString *first_like_user=user_post.recent_like_name;
    int count=(int)[first_like_user length];
    int like_count=[user_post.like_count intValue];

    //chek if tehre are any likes on the post
    NSLog(@"post id is %@",user_post.id);
    NSLog(@"recent like name is %@",user_post.recent_like_name);
    NSLog(@"like count is %d",like_count);

    if(like_count>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"inside like count block");
        cell.label_like_count.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell.label_like_count sizeToFit];
        [cell.label_like_count setHidden:false];
        NSString *str_like_count=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)like_count-1];
         if(like_count==1)
        {
            if([myUsername isEqualToString:first_like_user])
            {
                first_like_user=@"You asjlike sdfsdfsd sfd ";
                count=3;

            }
            else
            {
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" like this post"];


            }

        }
        else if(like_count==2)
        {
            first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
            str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@" other like this post"];
            first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_like_count];

        }
        else
        {
            if(like_count>1000)
            {
                like_count=like_count/1000;
                str_like_count=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)like_count];
                str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@"k"];
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
                str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@" others like this post"];
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_like_count];
            }
            else
            {
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
                str_like_count=[str_like_count stringByAppendingString:@" others like this post"];
                first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:str_like_count];

            }


        }
        mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:first_like_user];

        attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

        [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
        [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

        [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];

        [cell.label_like_count setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not inside like count");
        [cell.label_like_count setHidden:true];


    }


   // show dynamic comment
    NSMutableArray *user_comments=user_post.comments;
    float comment_count=[user_post.comment_count intValue];
    NSLog(@"post id is %@",user_post.id);
    NSLog(@"arr comments count is %lu",(unsigned long)comment_count);
    NSLog(@"arr user comments count is %lu",[user_comments count]);
    if(comment_count>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"post id is %@",user_post.id);

        //make label multiline
        cell.first_comment.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell.first_comment sizeToFit];
        cell.second_cmment.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell.second_cmment sizeToFit];
        cell.third_comment.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell.third_comment sizeToFit];

        NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeStr;
        NSAttributedString *attributeStr;
        if(comment_count==1)
        {
            [cell.first_comment setHidden:false];
            [cell.second_cmment setHidden:true];
            [cell.third_comment setHidden:true];

        }
        else if(comment_count==2)
        {
            [cell.first_comment setHidden:false];
            [cell.second_cmment setHidden:false];
            [cell.third_comment setHidden:true];

        }
        else
        {
            [cell.first_comment setHidden:false];
            [cell.second_cmment setHidden:false];
            [cell.third_comment setHidden:false];
            [cell.btn_more_comments setHidden:false];

        }
        for(l=0;l<[user_comments count];l++)
        {
            NSLog(@"inside loop %d",l);
            Comment *comment=[user_comments objectAtIndex:l];
            NSLog(@"comment is %@",comment.comment);
            NSLog(@"comment user is %@",comment.user_name);
            if(l==0)
            {
                NSLog(@"l is zero");
                NSString *comment_string=[comment.user_name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
                comment_string=[comment_string stringByAppendingString:comment.comment];
                int count=(int)[comment.user_name length];
                mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];
                NSLog(@"comment string is %@",comment_string);
                attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

                [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
                [cell.first_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];


            }
            else if(l==1)
            {
                 NSLog(@"l is 1");
                NSString *comment_string=[comment.user_name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
                comment_string=[comment_string stringByAppendingString:comment.comment];
                int count=(int)[comment.user_name length];
                mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];

                attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                NSLog(@"comment string is %@",comment_string);
                [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
                [cell.second_cmment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
            }
            else if(l==2)
            {
                 NSLog(@"l is 2");
                NSString *comment_string=[comment.user_name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
                comment_string=[comment_string stringByAppendingString:comment.comment];
                int count=(int)[comment.user_name length];
                mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:comment_string];

                attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]  range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
                [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[self colorFromHexString:@"#48a0dd"] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

                [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
                [cell.third_comment setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.first_comment setHidden:true];
        [cell.second_cmment setHidden:true];
        [cell.third_comment setHidden:true];
        [cell.btn_more_comments removeFromSuperview];

    }
    cell.label_time.text=[BaseController getTimestampForDate:date];
    [arr_indexpath addObject:indexPath];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: show your cell for rowatIndexpath method

Comment: What do you have in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: PLAESE CHECK MY UPDATED CODE

Comment: omg your method is too big. I was lost looking for a textview.

Comment: sorry but i have this only

Comment: can you please suggest why this issue will come that only on scroll the height will change ?@Mr.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try call  `[cell layoutIfNeeded];`& replace `self.table_view` with `tabelview`.This may solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
-(void)dynamicTextSize{
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 200, 30)];
textView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:textView];

NSString *string  = @"You long text here";
textView.text = string;

//UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0f];
NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:textView.font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];

textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

CGRect frame  = [textView.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, 10000) options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attrDict context:nil];

CGRect mFrame = textView.frame;
mFrame.size.width = frame.size.width;
mFrame.size.height = frame.size.height;
textView.frame = mFrame;

//NSLog(@"frame2:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame));
}
```

Comment: I am able to change the textview height but why this happned only on scroll?